# Trying to make navbar image appear based on which page user is on

Tags: html, css

I currently have my navbar set to change the image of navbar items when a user hovers over them, but I also want it to change an image from its default to that hovered image when a user clicks on that image and is sent over to another page. I'm trying to do this with the `active` property, but it doesn't seem to be working.

**HTML:**

```
<a href="index.html" >
                    <div class="navbar-image" id="navbar-image-ID2Games">
                    </div>

                    <br>
                    <div class="navbar-text">
                        ID2 Games
                    </div>
                </a>
```

**CSS:**

```
#navbar-image-ID2Games { 
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 3.5rem; 
    height: 3.5rem; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/Ou5cX4D.png); 
    background-size: contain;
} 

#navbar-image-ID2Games:hover {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 3.5rem; 
    height: 3.5rem; 
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/Tx0SVZr.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}

#navbar-image-ID2Games:active {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 3.5rem; 
    height: 3.5rem; 
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/Tx0SVZr.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

JSFiddle to give you an idea: https://jsfiddle.net/y1yv54qu/1/

Comment: when you click that element, the parent element which is `a` tag is redirecting the page to `index.html`. In this case, changing the background when click seems useless.

Answer (score 0):

what about a jquery solution?

```
<a href="#"><div class="navbar-image original"></div></a>
```

CSS

```
.navbar-image {
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
background-position:center;
display:block;
width: 3.5rem; 
height: 3.5rem; 
}
.navbar-image:hover {
 background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/Tx0SVZr.png);
}
.original{
background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/Ou5cX4D.png);
}
.new-nav{
background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/Tx0SVZr.png);
}
```

Jquery

```
$('.navbar-image').on({
click: function(){
$(this).addClass('new-nav').removeClass('original');
                }
});
```

Demo
http://jsfiddle.net/sandiiev/ee293mbo/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:focus` to have something similar behaviour as click event.

To make this work, you need to use `tabindex` attribute. For example,

> <div class="navbar-image" id="navbar-image-ID2Games" **tabindex="0"**>
>                       </div>

Then in CSS:

```
#navbar-image-ID2Games:focus {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/Tx0SVZr.png) no-repeat;
    outline: none; /* to remove default outline for focus elements */
    /* other styles */
}
```